# Spring Boot API returns 403 Forbidden as response to React App

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm trying to get my CSRF working. I have a Spring Boot API which has a post controller method, I'm trying to call it while sending along a CSRF-Token for it to work, but all I'm getting back is a 403 Forbidden response.

Spring Boot Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/token")
    public CsrfToken csrf(CsrfToken token){
        return token;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/postendpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<?> somePost(String text){
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
                .body(text);
    }
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and().cors();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Request from React:

```
response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/tasks/token', {withCredentials: true}).then((tokenResp) => {
      console.log(tokenResp);

      return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/tasks/postendpoint',
        {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': tokenResp.data.token
          }
        }
      );
    }).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

some of the dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you added @crossorigin to your controller class?

Comment: @Daksharajkamal Yessir